# ASP.NET core | How to use same variable in HTML file and Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on my first webapp in visual studio and I'm having a problem.
In my HTML file I want to declare a variable that I can use in my javascript file, but I do not know how.
I know the basics of html, but I don't know much javascript (but I need to use it).
Is there a way I can declare a variable in my html script and use the same variable with the same given value in an other javascript file[image]

So the variable needs to be used in API.js and registreerPagina.csHTML

Thanks in advance for helping me!!

Comment: Files don't use any variables, if you've loaded that JS file into a HTML document, then you can refer the variable with its name in any script, providing the variable is declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is just to put a  tag in your HTML. This will just inject the javascript into your page.

```
<script>var msg = "Hello world";</script>
```

But because Javascript is a script, you need to be sure that your  tag is rendered before your javascript file tries to use it. That's a bit more of a complex subject, but this is the basic idea if you just want to declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the server-side structure, the resulting client-side is ultimately just one "page" in the browser and any JavaScript on or referenced by that page is executed by the browser.  So in that page you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = 'some value';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="someFile.js"></script>
```

If there's code in `someFile.js` which references a window-level variable called `x` then that variable will at that time have the value `'some value'`.  All of the JavaScript loaded, whether on the page or references in a separate file, will be executed in the order it's loaded and all under the same window context.

In structures such as ASP.NET this can be useful when a value is dynamic in the view and needs to be used in the JavaScript, which sounds like the situation you're experiencing.  Suppose you design your JavaScript file such that it gets loaded and then needs to be invoked with some injected values.  You can have something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="someFile.js"></script>

<!-- lots of page content, then at the bottom... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = '@someServerSideValue';
    invokeJS(x);
</script>
```

In this case there could be lots of code within `someFile.js`, but it's all just defined and not actually executed yet.  Its execution is wrapped in a function to be invoked when the page finishes loading.  (In this case that function is called `invokeJS`.)  That function expects a parameter (or multiple parameters) to provide it with values needed by that code, much like dependency injection.

Comment: This is a nice, comprehensive answer, because it also explains about setting the variable dynamically server side.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a couple of ways you could approach this. The first method would be to create an API controller in your application and call the endpoint to return your value/values:

```
// Assuming you have referenced jQuery
$(function() {
    $.getJSON("/api/schweetvariable", function(data) {
        localVar = data;
    });
 });
```

The other way would be to generate the JS file from the server side via a httphandler or similar. Honestly, I'd go the API route as its pretty straightforward and easy to implement and maintain.

There are a few other ways you could achieve this: SignalR with a persistent connection or inline your `API.js` logic if that's an option.